# How to improve write performance in OrientDB graph for supernodes?

Tags: neo4j, orientdb, graph-databases

I'm currently seeing low concurrent write performance when adding edges to vertices which already have many edges. Vertices which aggregate other vertices with lots of edges are called *supernodes*.

Supernodes cause multiple issues:

### Degrading write performance

Adding new edges will gradually slow down with each added edge.

The reason was stated by OrientDB:

> Unfortunately there is no way to add edges to vertices without loading all the connected structures.

### Contention when handling concurrent requests

When concurrently adding new vertices the supernodes need to be updated as well. This can be quickly determined by checking which nodes have a high version number.

`SELECT @version, @rid, @class from V where @version >40 order by @version DESC`

Concurrent updates on the same elements will cause expected errors which require the user to retry the transaction again. This is due to the MVCC pattern that OrientDB uses and expected.

This will require the transaction to be retried. This will cause a significant reduction in write speed.

### Options

What options exist to improve performance in this situation?

Options I found:

- Remove supernodes (not always possible)
- Segment supernodes by adding edges and vertices to this vertex to which the actually aggregated vertices can connect.
- Remove supernodes and replace them instead with indexed properties
  The child vertices contain the property which identifies the "collection" to which they belong. A index can thus be used to quickly find all vertices in this collection.

### Questions

I don't know yet how OrientDB can handle contention on indices which may happen when adding index entries. I assume this kind of contention can be handled more efficiently and may not cause errors that require a tx retry.

I know that it is possible to add explicit locks with OrientDB. Would these locks help deal with contention issues? Are those locks distributed to other cluster nodes?

Are there any other factors which I have overlooked?

How do databases like Neo4j deal with contention and supernodes? Do similar limitations apply?